# Ship detection with ArcGIS Pro - deep learning

Tags: arcgis-pro, deep-learning

Currently I try to develop and apply a deep learning model to detect vessels. I imported aerial imagery (3 bands, Color Infrared, 25 cm resolution, ECW files) and created manually about 200 training samples of ships. As software I used ArcGIS Pro 2.5 in combination with Jupyter Notebook.

I exported the training samples to image chips and trained a model with 78% accuracy in Jupyter Notebook which looks promising. 
As a last step I used the 'Detect Objects for Deep Learning' tool in ArcGIS Pro to apply my model. Part of the results are shown in the image below:

[image: Results of Detect Objects for Deep Learning tool]

Did I something wrong that I get different predictions for actually one individual ship?
I hoped to get something like this:

[image: Expected result (created with an editor]

Any suggestions how could I improve my results?

Comment: I would imagine to get any sort of an answer you would need to significantly improve this question with all your tool parameters?

Comment: Given the nature of the model, it would seem that generating a non-orthagonal rectangle would require additional effort, and that clustering what you have might just be the next step in your process.